# Django: ForeignKey() or ManyToMany() in this case? Or, other?

Tags: django, design-patterns, database-design

I have a model that is something like this:

```
class ReturnAuthorization(models.Model):
    custom_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class RMAAPILog(models.Model):
    return_authorization = models.ForeignKey(ReturnAuthorization)
```

If I were to **delete()** a return authorization, I can't have it delete all the `RMAAPILog()s` that are related to it. In this case they get deleted. There can be many attempts to get an RMA from the outside API (so many `RMAAPILog()`s per `ReturnAuthorization()`, but there can only be one ReturnAuthorization() for each RMAAPILog() of course because it's a log of an attempt to authorize a specific `ReturnAuthorization()`. What would be the better way to do this, or am I thinking of it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related SO question: [How do I create a Django model with ForeignKeys which does not cascade deletes to its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006135/how-do-i-create-a-django-model-with-foreignkeys-which-does-not-cascade-deletes-to)

Comment: Oops, That's not right. That post is about a guy having the opposite problem. He has a model that he needs this cascading on but it isn't working. I need the opposite effect. I need to delete the parent without the child being deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't tell if that matched or not. Doesn't one of the answers apply though? "Django's ForeignKey manager has a method called clear() that removes all objects from the related object set. Calling that first, then deleting your object should work." - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006135/how-do-i-create-a-django-model-with-foreignkeys-which-does-not-cascade-deletes-to/1007778#1007778

Comment: There is a patch in http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7539 to add support for controlling ON DELETE behavior in the model.

Comment: Sweet, that patch is what I'm looking for. Thanks.