# How do you prevent Django's cascading delete on a User object?

Tags: django, django-admin

When a User (auth.user) is deleted, I'd like to prevent the cascading delete from clearing certain tables.  How can I prevent Django's User model from executing the cascading delete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a Django model with ForeignKeys which does not cascade deletes to its children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006135/how-do-i-create-a-django-model-with-foreignkeys-which-does-not-cascade-deletes-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1:

- Ensure all the objects that link to the target object you want to delete support null=True
- For the object you want to delete, iterate through all of reverse relations (ie, the ones that point back to the object you're deleting) and set them to to `None`, remembering to save
- Delete your target object.

Option 2:

- Use Django 1.3 -> http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3-alpha-1/#configurable-delete-cascade

Comment: Definetly nowadays the solution is **Option 2**

Answer (score 0):

Use newly released django 1.3a1

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete